# How to stop sage graph generating iterator after N iterations?

Tags: python, iterator, sage

I want to create N planar graphs using sagemath's graph.planar_graphs iterator. The problem is that this function return **all** possible planar graphs given a certain number of vertices. What I want to do is something like:

```
while len(gen) < N:
    gen = list(graphs.planar_graphs(50))
```

So in the end, I want a list with the first N generated planar graphs instead of **all** of them (since thats many orders of magnitudes more graphs and computationally very expensive).

Comment: Also asked as [Ask Sage question 56313](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/56313).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice thing about iterators is you can grab
as many or as few elements as you want.

Iterator for all planar graphs of order 50:

```
sage: planar_50 = graphs.planar_graphs(50)
```

Grab the first four:

```
sage: planar_50_4 = [next(planar_50) for _ in range(4)]
```

Check:

```
sage: planar_50_4
[Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices]
```

Turn that into a function:

```
def planar_graphs_order_k_first_n(k, n):
    pg = graphs.planar_graphs(k)
    return [next(pg) for _ in range(n)]
```

Use it:

```
sage: planar_graphs_order_k_first_n(50, 4)
[Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices,
 Graph on 50 vertices]
```